# Making contact us form using elastic email and smtpjs

Tags: html, contact-form

#html#

```
<div class="s-4 w-full p-5" id="contact">
                                <div class="contact mt-16 max-w-md rounded-md flex flex-col justify-center items-left px-5 py-2 mx-auto text-black">
                                                <h1 class="section-title-h text-center text-4xl text-white mb-10" data-aos="fade-up">Contact Us</h1>
                                                <form onsubmit="SubmitForm(); reset(); return false">
                                                <label class="block mb-4" data-aos="fade-up">
                                                            <!--    <span class="block text-sm text-white font-medium">Name</span> -->
                                                                <input type="text" placeholder="Your Name Here" id="name" class=" py-8 px-2 border-solid border-b-2 border-gray-600 w-full h-10 outline-0 bg-black focus:border-gray-100 ease-in-out duration-500 text-white"/>
                                                </label>
                                                <label class="block mb-4" data-aos="fade-up">
                                                            <!--    <span class="block text-sm text-white font-medium">E-mail</span> -->
                                                                <input type="email" placeholder="Enter a valid E-mail" name="email" id="email" class=" py-8 px-2 border-solid border-b-2 border-gray-600 w-full h-10 outline-0 bg-black focus:border-gray-100 ease-in-out duration-500 text-white">
                                                </label>
                                                <label class="block mb-4" data-aos="fade-up">
                                                        <!--        <span class="block text-sm text-white font-medium">Message</span> -->
                                                                <textarea rows="4"  placeholder="Your message here" id="message" class=" py-8 px-2 border-solid border-b-2 border-gray-600 w-full h-10 outline-0 bg-black focus:border-gray-100 ease-in-out duration-500 text-white"></textarea>
                                                </label>
                                                <label class="block w-full h-auto flex justify-center items-center ">
                                                                <input type="submit" placeholder="send" class="w-32 px-2 py-2 rounded-3xl bg-black  border border-3 border-gray-600 text-gray-400 hover:bg-gray-600 text-xl"/>
                                                </label>
                                    
                                    
                                                </form>
                                </div>
                </div>
```

#javascript#

```
function SubmitForm() {
    try{
                    Email.send({ 
        Host : "smtp.gmail.com", 
        Username : "pnishant2323@gmail.com", 
        Password : "PASSWORD", 
        To : 'pnishant2323@gmail.com', 
        From : document.getElementById("email").value, 
        Subject : "New Query from Client", 
        Body : "Name: " + document.getElementById("name").value 
                + "<br>" +
                "E-mail: " + document.getElementById("email").value
                + "<br>" +
                "Message: " + document.getElementById("message").value`enter code here`
                
    })
    .then(res=>{console.log(res)});
    } catch(err) {
                    console.log(err)
    }
}
```

> The erroe I am getting after submiting the form is
>
> **Mailbox name not allowed. The server response was: Envelope FROM
> 'johndoe@gmail.com' email address not allowed.**
>
> does anyone has any solution for it

Comment: I believe the from address should be the same as the username.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are trying to send an email with someone's else name. For example, if the user gives as input billgates@microsoft.com you're supposed to send a message with this email, but you cannot do this because that email is not yours, and you cannot use it. So to fix this in your `From : document.getElementById("email").value,`  you need to use your email which is: `pnishant2323@gmail.com`.